# Adding font and importing with PDF generator in PHP

Tags: php, fonts, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm generating PDF documents in PHP. I'm importing templates and using custom fonts. Until now I've used FPDF (with UFPDF & FPDFI), but now I have to add a certain font which FPDF doesn't seem to handle: crossed boxes are added before every character.

I tried switching to TCPDF which does accept the font, but it doesn't seem to handle importing. There's a subclass (TCPDF_IMPORT) but it's experimental and it outputs garbage in my case.

Thankfully accepting hints on how to tackle this!

**TL;DR:** FPDFI handles importing but not my font. TCPDF handles my font but not importing. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using TCPDF together with FPDI. See http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/ for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

So for FPDF you called `MakeFont(string fontfile, [, string enc [, boolean embed]])` ?

I think it's definitely in the encoding (second argument for MakeFont()).

Have you tried everything at from the documentation: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm